# How to get global pointer to view controller in swift

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, swift, uipopovercontroller

I'm building an app using swift. In my app, I need to present a UIPopoverPresentationController, and I also need to acces the content controller from that popover from other methods in my normal view controller.

To do this, I would normally in objective C just create a global pointer to my view controller, which would allow me to access it from any method.

This is how I would do it in Swift:

```
class Categories: UITableViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
var newCategory = self.storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewCategory") as NewCategory

//rest of my code
```

When I do this, Xcode gives me the error:

```
Categories.type does not have a member named 'storyBoard'
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I need to modify my code to create a legit global pointer to my view controller? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: First of all: "as NewCategory" looks wrong because there should be type of variable. For example: "var newCategory: NSData = NSData() as NSData". And check you sensitivities to case (like storyBoard and storyboard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use @lazy attribute for this. Bellow is general receipt:

```
class MyClass {
    let compileTimeProperty = "compileTimePropert"

    @lazy var runTimeProperty:String = {
        return self.compileTimeProperty
    }()
}
```

And here is how your code should be adjusted:

```
class Categories: UITableViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

    @lazy var newCategory: NewCategory = {
        return self.storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewCategory") as NewCategory
    }()

    //rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are putting that `var` declaration outside of any code (i.e. at the top level of the Categories class, not inside any function). You cannot refer to `self` in the default value of a variable declaration outside of a `func` unless you also declare that variable as `@lazy`.

Thus in general:

```
class MyClass {
    let howdy = "howdy"
    var hello = self.howdy // illegal

    func f() {
        var hello = self.howdy // legal
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is only giving default values for `storyBoard` and `newCategory`, but Swift does not guarantee that the default property values will be initialized in any particular order. Consequently, it's illegal to reference another property in the default value for one. Move the code for setting those values into an `init` and it should work fine:

```
class Categories: UITableViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

let storyBoard: UIStoryboard
var newCategory: NewCategory

init {
    storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    newCategory = self.storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewCategory") as NewCategory
}

//rest of code
```

To be clear on terminology: declaring variables at the top level of class like this doesn't make them "global variables", it makes the properties of the class. (Global variables are declared outside the scope of any class/struct/function.) Also, the rules for properties are different from other variables, in that you do NOT need to assign a value when you declare them (and if you do, it's only treated as a default value) -- the real requirement is that you must either provide a default value, OR assign a value in the initializer.

But for this particular case, Keenle's `@lazy` solution is the more appropriate choice.

Comment: Okay, But if i put `var newCategory = self.storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewCategory") as UIViewController` inside an init, I'm not creating a global variable anymore and that is what I needed. Do you know how I would be able to make it a global variable anyway?

Comment: Xcode sais type annotation missing in Pattern, What do I need to add to hep that?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was sloppy. The property declarations need type annotations, of course.