# Segueing to another view from a custom cell button in SWIFT for ios app

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am coding an ios app in swift.
I have a ViewController holding a custom table view, which holds a custom cell. Each cell has a switch, upon which activating, I would like the view to segue to a second viewcontroller.

I am attempting to achieve this by declaring a storyboard variable, and instatiating the second view controller, and pushing to the second view controller. I’ve searched the boards for solutions, however none of them seem to work.

Within class customCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell

Try 1:

```
customCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let view2: viewController2 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("View2") as viewController2
switchActive fnc(){

self.window?.rootViewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(view2, animated: true)

}

…
//rest of code
```

Error: customCellTableViewCell.Type does not have member named storyboard

Try 2:

```
customCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

init(storyboard: UIStoryboard){
        self.storyboard = storyboard
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

var storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let view2: viewController2 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("View2") as viewController2
switchActive fnc(){

self.window?.rootViewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(view2, animated: true)

}

…
//rest of code
```

Error: customCellTableViewCell.Type does not have member named storyboard

Try 3:

```
customCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


var storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let view2: viewController2 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("View2") as viewController2

switchActive fnc(){

self.window?.rootViewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(view2, animated: true)

}

…
//rest of code
```

Put code inside of switchActive fnc, but does not work.
Replaced var with let, to no avail.
Tried suggestion in this post, using the lazy attribute
[How to get global pointer to view controller in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24724235/how-to-get-global-pointer-to-view-controller-in-swift)

I cannot figure out what I’m doing wrong. I’ve been stuck for a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Storyboard are very convenient for segueing.
1) In your storyboard create the 2 views controllers (I supposed it already done)

2) Create a segue between the 2 view controllers(hold ctrl + click from the first ViewController to the second one, It will ask you wich segue type do you want, choose "show").

3)Give an identifier to that Segue (click on the link and on the right panel in the 4th tab)

4)In your first View Controller, when the switch is activated,

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("detail", sender:nil)
```

Replace identifier "detail" with the identifier that you chose.